# Complicated Inner Join

Tags: sql

I have two tables, `t1` and `t2`. `t1` contains the fields `file_id`, `start` and `end`.
`t2` contains the fields `start`, `end` and `loc`. What I want to do is have an `inner join` between `t1` and `t2` with the following conditions:

```
t1.start >= t2.start AND t1.end <= t2.end
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Really?, it should probably be `t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.start >= t2.start AND t1.end <= t2.end AND t1.file_id = t2.loc`

Answer (score 1):

By joining on those criteria

```
 Select * from
 t1 inner join t2
    on t1.start >= t2.start AND t1.end <= t2.end
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you basically have it:

```
select <whatever>
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.start >= t2.start and t1.end <= t2.end
```

Is there something else you need?